# Convert button to on hover transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've come across the following code online for a nice button that when clicked appears to be pressed.

**I'd like to add a transition with the button appearing pressed on hover not on click**.

How can I do this?

```css
/**
 * AddToCalendar Icon Style
 * http://addtocalendar.com
 */

/* Base */

.addtocalendar var{
    display: none;
}

.addtocalendar {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent!important;
}

.atcb-link {
    display: block;
    outline: none!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.atcb-link:focus~ul,
.atcb-link:active~ul,
.atcb-list:hover{
    visibility:visible;
}

.atcb-list {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 900;
}

.atcb-list,
.atcb-item
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.atcb-item {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.atcb-item-link
{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
}

.atcb-item.hover,
.atcb-item:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}


/* Orange */

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-list{
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link
{
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(219,87,5,1);
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease;
    transition: all .1s ease;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:hover,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:active,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 7px 25px;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-list {
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgb(186,186,186);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #AAA;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-list,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;

}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link
{
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:hover,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:active,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:focus
{
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:hover,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:active,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item-link:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(219,87,5,1);
}

.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item.hover,
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-item:hover {
    background: rgba(250,203,175,1);
}
```

```html
            <span class="addtocalendar atc-style-glow-orange" id="atc_btn_orange" data-on-button-click="atcButtonClick" data-on-calendar-click="atcCalendarClick">
                <a class="atcb-link">Add to Calendar</a>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 0):

Provide hover to the class which you need like,

```
.classname:hover{
   background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:active {
```

to this:

```
.atc-style-glow-orange .atcb-link:hover {
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrxwc39r/)

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above this works when I approach the button from the side or bottom, but if I approach from the top the button dances around like a Turkey on Christmas eve. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, this is because when u hover the button, it moves and leaves this white space on top (giving the overall effect of the button being pressed). But at the same time, when moving down, the it move away from under the cursor, which causes the button **not** to be in hovered mode anymore, and hence the button moves back to its previous position (and back under ur cursor), which re-triggers the move down on hover effect as a loop. But since hover effect is an event on ur cursor moving from one pixel to another, the to and fro movement keeps repeating itself.

Comment: Also, u can use `transform: translateY(6px);` instead of `top: 6px;`, CSS will apply the transition effect making it look smoother, [like so...](http://jsfiddle.net/nrxwc39r/2/)